# What is difference between vault write and vault kv put?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm currently learning about vault. I know what is a secret engine etc and how it works. But I have not found any information about difference between `vault write` and `vault kv put`. In my opinion these commands do the same things. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, write was used in previous versions of the k/v secret engine.

According to the Vault documentaion, it's better to use put. Write may still be avaible and the only difference might be that in k/v version 2 instead of appending secrets it overrides them.

Comment: Can you give the url to the documentation where is written that is better used kv put?

Comment: No documentation directly says that "is better", but they use only put for making request in the current version, so write might be deprecated. [Here](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/kv/index.html)'s the documentation for the k/v secret engine.

Comment: I find this painfully confusing. "all while using the same read/write interface" https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/getting-started/secrets-engines.html#what-is-a-secrets-engine- .. except for KV.

Comment: @MarkM that sentence doesn't seems to be related to this question. It talks about the overall secret engine, but in this thread we are talking about the k/v secret engine

Comment: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/index.html it says "The original version of K/V used the common read and write operations. A more advanced K/V Version 2 engine was released in Vault 0.10 and introduced the kv get and kv put commands."